# Calendar lightning component to display on home page

Tags: lightning, home-page-component, calendar, role-hierarchy

Does anyone know an appexchange with a lightning component that would display the current user's calendar and the users calendars below in the hierarchy (as in Classic)? I would like to display this component on the homepage.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The AnyCalendar lightning component by Salesforce Labs allows you to drop a calendar into Lightning Experience or Napili Template Communities. In the builder you can select a standard or custom object and customize the calendar display options. You can customize this as per your requirement.

Reference:- [AnyCalendar](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000Ev8qpUAB)

Comment: I have already tried it and it displays all the calendars I need. But there is no legend: all the events of all calendars are displayed without any color or something to distinguish between users.
And for now I am looking for an existing solution without having to code.